# Colors.js: Proper syntax for adding a color to a variable (string)?

Tags: node.js, colors, express

In addition to my static message (which displays just fine), how would I make the variable named 'port' green in this console.log?

```
console.log('Express app started on port '.green + port);
```

I don't see anything about adding colors to variables in the docs, and of course if I just add .green to port, it will look for the .green element of the port var which will be undefined.

Using: https://github.com/Marak/colors.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`colors.js` modifies the string object -- try

```
port.toString().green
```